# How to put all CSV files in a folder with OS module - python

Tags: python, csv, operating-system, file-handling

I am writing a program that deals with file handling and I am creating different CSV files in that program. Using the python OS module I am trying to create a folder and puts all the CSV files that would be created in it. How can I carry this out? I saw this method but it doesn't seem to work, is there any other way I can perform this.

```
main_dir = "C:/MONIFY FOLDER"

os.mkdir(main_dir)
print("Directory '% s' created" % main_dir)
os.chdir("/MONIFY FOLDER")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print("DONE")
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific: _"all the CSV files"_? Sidenote: The snippet you grabbed somewhere is using Pandas and is combining all csv-files in one folder into one single csv-file ... ?

Comment: In the program, I am creating different CSV files. How can I put all the CSV files to be created in a folder after executing the program? Without doing it manually

Comment: That is still too vague: The files could be scattered all over the place, could be all in one folder, ...? You probably won't get an answer if you don't provide this information.